# Impossible to fetch SKProducts in App extensions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

`SKProductsRequest` always fails in my Action Extension, with this error:

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

It works fine in the main app.

Is it a deliberate limitation?

Comment: Some APIs are unavailable to app extensions. You also cannot use any APIs with the NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE macro in the header. Although I cannot find anything specific I would think the StoreKit framework is not allowed.

Comment: @Bamsworld It's not NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE otherwise it cannot compile.

Comment: @an0 Did you get luck of using SKProductsRecust from the action extension?

Comment: @Ramis no, I didn't.